# use ssh connection with a linux service

Tags: linux, ssh, service

I created my 1st service and the main executable is a shell script A which invokes another script B that I don't have any control.

Merely run my script A, it's calling B and everything is OK.
while before that I copied my ssh key to some server C for which script B use `ssh root@servrC's IP`.

But when I set up my service, it's stuck at the `ssh root@ip` line in script B and `returned non-zero exit status 255`.

Comment: This is kind of permission problem, will try to add root ssh key along with current one.

Answer (score 0):

figure it out by myself but I think it's not a perfect one I expect.

Just switch to root as default user for the service instead of a common user though which was set with the service's configuration file.

Expect more solutions.